# Dyer-Lashof operations and the homology of GL_n

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, homology

For any ring R, $\bigsqcup_n {BGL}_n(R)$ is an $E_\infty$-space. Are there examples of rings where people have calculated $H_*(\bigsqcup_n {BGL}_n(R);\mathbb{Z}/2)$ and determined the Dyer-Lashof operations?

Comment: Do you necessarily want $\amalg_n BGL_n(R)$ or would you be ok with the group completion (the homology is not *that* different)? It seems to me that it would be easier to look for results on the homology of algebraic K-theory.

Answer (score 6):

Taking the ring of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$, the paper of Priddy

`DYER-LASHOF OPERATIONS FOR THE CLASSIFYING SPACES OF CERTAIN MATRIX GROUPS' Quart J. Math. Oxford (3), 26 (1975), 179-93

provides example of computations and detailed formula of the sort you may look for, bearing in mind that in these cases the monoid you take, is homotopy equivalent to the one considered in the paper.

Comment: Here is a complementary and earlier reference: Stanley O. Kochman. Homology of the classical groups over the Dyer-Lashof algebra. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 185 (1973), 83-136.